# Get filename of my crystal report as Caption in a form in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string="`C:\\PerxClub\\PerxClub\\Reports\\CrystalReport1.rpt`"

I want to get "`CrystalReport1.rpt`" only to use as caption on my form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GetFilename http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

```
string path = @"C:\PerxClub\PerxClub\Reports\CrystalReport1.rpt";
string result = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for your quick response, GOD bless you!

Comment: Happy to Help. @odlanyer If this has resolved your issue you can mark it as the answer by clicking the tick next to the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry Im new member here! Hope to here from you soon.